# Wordpress - how to remove header

Tags: php, wordpress

I added a Wordpress blog on a website. This is how it looks so far: http://alweso.2ap.pl/blog/?m=201403

I would like to get rid of the header area - for the menu to be on top, so it resembles the non-Wordpress pages. I'm a complete newbie if it comes to PHP - what should I remove or add? I'm guessing I should play with header.php, so here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class() ?>>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header id="header">
        <<?php pinboard_title_tag( 'site' ); ?> id="site-title">
            <?php if ( ( '' != get_header_image() ) &&  ( false != get_header_image() ) ) : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" rel="home">
                    <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" width="<?php echo ( pinboard_get_option( 'retina_header' ) ? absint( get_custom_header()->width / 2 ) : get_custom_header()->width ); ?>" height="<?php echo ( pinboard_get_option( 'retina_header' ) ? absint( get_custom_header()->height / 2 ) : get_custom_header()->height ); ?>" />
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <a class="home" href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
        </<?php pinboard_title_tag( 'site' ); ?>>
        <?php if( ! is_active_sidebar( 1 ) ) : ?>
            <<?php pinboard_title_tag( 'desc' ); ?> id="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></<?php pinboard_title_tag( 'desc' ); ?>>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php get_sidebar( 'header' ); ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <nav id="access">
            <a class="nav-show" href="#access">Show Navigation</a>
            <a class="nav-hide" href="#nogo">Hide Navigation</a>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary_nav' ) ); ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </nav><!-- #access -->
    </header><!-- #header -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary_nav' ) ); ?>
```

This function showing your nav menu, show you have to call this function , wherever you want to show the menu.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that info, but what can I REMOVE then? I see some sidebars in the code so I'm not sure if leaving only the piece of code you gave wouldn't cause some problems.

Comment: Update:

I removed everything under header down to <nav> and it seems to be working fine :) Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

with CSS it can be done, in your style.css (**/blog/wp-content/themes/pinboard/style.css**)

ADD change next:

```
#site-title {
margin: 0 3.4%;
font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
font-size: 32px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

into:

```
#site-title {
margin: 0 3.4%;
font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
font-size: 32px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
visibility: hidden;
height: 0px;
}
```

and:

```
#site-title, #site-description {
margin: 0;
font-weight: 300;
float: left;
line-height: 150px;
}
```

into:

```
#site-title, #site-description {
margin: 0;
font-weight: 300;
float: left;
line-height: 150px;
visibility: hidden;
height: 0px;
}
```

and:

```
#header #searchform {
float: right;
margin: 60px 3.4% 0 3px;
}
```

into:

```
#header #searchform {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

it will give this result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution, Danny, but I managed to deal with this issue right before you posted your answer. I vote it up anyway, as it seems you were pretty close.

Comment: Your welcome and thanks for the vote.
Sometimes people forget that they can change a lot with the lay-out with the css files, instead changing PHP or HTML code

Comment: Definately. In this case I prefer the php solution though, as the navbar is right on top (no space between screen and navbar), but I bet it could be achieved via CSS alone as you mentioned. It's just that it's the first time I added a wordpress blog to a website and it still seems a bit of black magic, I tend to forget that things are meant to be simple :)